# Redux store does not have a valid reducer, with combineReducers and valid reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => state
const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducer)
let store = createStore(rootReducer)
export default store
```

A warning is triggered when the store is created:

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
```

This warning comes up again when I attempt to use any of the store methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is simple - you did not pass an object to combineReducers:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ reducer })
```

This will fix the problem.